# Select from mysql not equal to

Tags: mysql

Hello I'm working on a web application using PHP as server side language and im trying to select from MySql Database where value not equal "something"
I found many answers and I've tried all this select statements below but didn't work, sometimes it returns error or returns nothing noting that the column allows Null;

**What I have tried:**

```
 SELECT status from Orders  WHERE status <> 'canceled';
 SELECT status from Orders  WHERE status NOT IN ('canceled','deleted')
 SELECT status from Orders WHERE status NOT LIKE 'canceled'
 SELECT status from Orders WHERE status NOT LIKE '%canceled'
 SELECT status from Orders WHERE status <> 'canceled'
 SELECT status from Orders WHERE status != 'canceled'
 SELECT status from Orders WHERE NOT status='canceled'
```

Comment: please create a sql fiddle and share the link

Comment: `SELECT `status` from `Orders` WHERE status NOT IN ('canceled','deleted')`

Comment: you sure that `canceled` isn't supposed to read as `cancelled`? because that's how the word is spelled in English.

Comment: so you accepted an answer below. I can't see how doing `SELECT *` over `SELECT status` could make a differerence here. You already tried `SELECT status from Orders  WHERE status NOT IN ('canceled','deleted')` and you didn't tell us what errors you were getting.

Comment: the issue is not `select *` or `select status` the issue is when the initial value is null the condition not work read the answer carefually

Comment: @PeterWilson and read *What I have tried:* `SELECT status from Orders  WHERE status NOT IN ('canceled','deleted')` what am I not grasping? and your answer `SELECT * FROM \`Orders\` WHERE   status NOT IN('canceled','deleted')` besides the asterisk and ticks difference. I'm leaning towards a possible typo `canceled` which probably is `cancelled` in their db.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've edited my Answer to be select status and again this will work if the column you try to check on it is not null I mean it has any value because if it was null the return of the SQL query will be always 0 rows, I am not sure why null values not working but this was the fix for me and for the original question

Comment: @PeterWilson I understand now Peter, thanks for the clarification. *Cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks Fred , I am sorry for lack of clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make Sure that the initial value of the column you need to check on is not **null** and then you could use

```
SELECT status FROM `Orders` WHERE   status NOT IN('canceled','deleted')
```